# html DOM file referencing an XML file won't print in browser

Tags: document.write

I am totally new to this and I am taking a class for fun that has now turned into a big headache. I have this html DOM file that references an XML file that I need to have show up on the screen in a browser. It should only print the elements of, title, first, last, location, discription. The CSS and Schema both validate fine and work. Should I still leave both of them in the the xml file when I using the html file? I get a blank on the browser screen. 
Thanks, Liam

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Catalog</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

         var xmlDoc;

         function loadXMLDoc() {

              // XML loader for IE

              if (window.ActiveXObject) {

                  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

                  xmlDoc.load("catalog.xml");

                 printCatalog();

            }

            // XML loader for other browsers

           else {

                xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);

                xmlDoc.load("catalog.xml");

                xmlDoc.onload = printCatalog;

          }
      }


      function printcatalog() {

          var titleNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");

          var firstNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("first");

          var lastNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("last");

          var locationNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("location");

         var descriptionNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description");

            for (var i = 0; i < titleNodes.length; i++) {

              document.write("<div style='font-family:arial; font-weight:bold;

                                      color:red'>" + 

                                    titleNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</div>");

              document.write("<div style='font-family:arial'>" +

                                     firstNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br />");

              document.write(lastNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br />");

             document.write(firstNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br />");

             document.write(locationNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br />");

             document.write(descriptionNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</div>");
           }


       }

 </script>

 </head>

<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">

</body>

</html>







 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.css" type="text/css"?>

 <catalog xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd"> 

 <course courseNum="CS205" area="ComputerScience">

 <title>Programming 1</title>

 <instructor>

 <first>Bill</first>

 <last>Gates</last>

 </instructor>

 <units>3</units>

<location>

<building>100</building>

<room>101</room>

</location>

 <description>Learn from the man himself, Mr. Microsoft. 

             Must love PCs and not Macs.</description>

</course>

<course courseNum="SS305" area="SocialStudies">

<title>Government 1945</title>

<instructor>

 <first>Karl</first>

 <last>Marx</last>

 </instructor>

<units>3</units>

<location>

<building>200</building>

<room>202</room>

</location>

<description>Mr. Marx will explain his political theories

          Lecture course. Bring lots of coffee.</description>
 </course>

<course courseNum="MA350" area="Math">

<title>Math 911</title>

 <instructor>

 <first>Albert</first>

 <last>Einstein</last>

 </instructor>

 <units>3</units>

<location>

<building>200</building>

 <room>302</room>

</location>

 <description>Find the answers to the universe in just one semester.

  </description>

</course>

  </catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use **document.write** after the page is loaded, because it will overwrite the already loaded DOM.

You should do something like:

```
<body>
   <script> 
       loadXMLDoc(); // call it while the page is loading
   </script>
</body>
```

Or if you don't want to call the loadXMLDoc(); early, you can change **document.write** to something else. May be an ugly version would be:

```
document.body.innerHTML += 'somestuff'
```

Or append text nodes to the body:

```
var doc = document.createTextNode('text here');
document.body.appendChild(doc);
```

Comment: I don't follow. I am totally a newbe. This HTML was taken from a book and only the elements were different. I was asked to just alter it to make it match my elements in my .XML file and maybe change the font or color of the text. It was suppose to be very simple alteration.

Comment: Oh, sorry :) First of all - what browser are you using? If you are using Firefox or Chrome, please try the example above with IE, as it is meant to run in IE :)  Then the changes in the code, may be the easiest for you is the second - just change document.write(...) to document.body.innerHTML += ...